# General term of the sequence and series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Whats is the general term of the sequence? for each value of n corresponding to the value of $f(n)$

$ f(n)=2,\;2,\;2,\;4,\;4,\;4,\;4,\;6,\;6,\;6,\;6,\;8,\;8,\;8,\;8,\;10,\;10,\;10,\;10 $; where $n = 2,3,4,...,20$
*i.e.* $f(2) = 2, \; f(3) = 2, \; f(4) = 2, \; f(5) = 6,\; ... , f(20) = 10$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f(n)=2\Big\lceil\frac{n}{4}\Big\rceil$$